# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMap'

Tags: mysql, spring, jakarta-ee, ibatis

this is code of applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="dataSource"
       class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
                  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />        
    <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlMap"
          class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:SqlMapConfig.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>    

    <bean id="tradingService"
        class="com.developersbook.ibatis.service.TradeServiceImpl">
        <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMap" />
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

these are the error logs

```
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3f5735fd: defining beans [dataSource,sqlMap,tradingService]; root of factory hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMap' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/SqlMapConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.developersbook.ibatis.client.IBatisClient.main(IBatisClient.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/SqlMapConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlMapClientFactoryBean.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: i trying to run this code but getting this exception i am using spring and ibatis both

Comment: "class path resource [src/SqlMapConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist" - where is SqlMapConfig.xml ?

Comment: Check your classpath. Double check file name on the file system. Minor spelling variations can be hard to spot and create annoying errors.

Comment: The log reminds you of the question: where did you put the file `SqlMapConfig.xml`? Is its containing directory on the classpath?

Comment: Your property file should go in src folder if your using classpath:yourfile